# JanusGraph loading with MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, janusgraph

I am using JanusGraph with HBase as storage backend. I currently have terrabytes of RDBMS data in HDFS. I would like to write a MapReduce code that transforms the RDBMS data to a graph format and then write that to JanusGraph.

I can't seem to find documentation around how to write a MapReduce code that can load JanusGraph using HBase as storage backend. If someone has any sample code, examples that would be great.